# JSF Session Beans

Tags: spring, jsf, session-variables

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class YesNoQuestion implements  Serializable {

    private final String questionText;
    private String response;

    public YesNoQuestion(String questionText) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }....
```

and another Session bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
   public class QuestionServiceImpl implements QuestionService {

        private Map<String, List<YesNoQuestion>> questionsMap;


    public QuestionServiceImpl(Map<String, List<YesNoQuestion>> questionsMap) {
        this.questionsMap = questionsMap;

    }
```

I have a list of YesNoQuestions which I use to generate a questionnaire on a JSF page and record the user's responses. There is a map which maps the product code to a particular questionnaire.

This works fine, however, I'm finding that as the list of questions has grown it takes a very long time to load the session bean (around 10 seconds in my prod server). In particular its quite wasteful as the question text can be very long but the response is very short (normally yes/no).

Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: I don't use Spring but somehow your classes looks a bit weird to me. I believe the `YesNoQuestion` should be a normal object instead of being a Session bean? As you have more and more questions, each question becomes 1 new bean? This sounds seriously wrong. Why do you need it to be a Session bean?

Comment: @Mr.J4mes because if the user goes back to the questionnaire page I want their answers to be there.

Comment: Your `QuestionServiceImpl` where you store the list of questions is already a Session bean. All of its properties (including the list of questions) will be automatically stored for you. Your `YesNoQuestion` can be a normal object. Implementing `Serializable` is enough.